# Creating teams based on two groups

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python, and I have a problem that I would like to solve (elegantly). I'm going to create teams for soccer matches this coming season. We have 24 players and would like to put them in two groups, 12 in each, based on skills. For each match, we want to select 8 players, 4 from each group. Ideally, everyone gets to play the same number of matches over the whole season. Does anyone know a simple way to do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363341/algorithm-to-create-fair-evenly-matched-teams-based-on-player-rankings

Comment: this really looks like homework...

Comment: I'm sorry to have bothered your divine intellects with such a trivial problem...

Comment: When you say 12 in each, is that top 12 and bottom 12? ..or two sets of 12 with skills shared out so both have a match?

Comment: @erikwkolstad: see it this way: we put about as much effort into our answers as you put into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by skill, pick from the top for alternating groups. Just like back in high school.