# Constraint satisfaction problem involving students with multiple variables

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

- Very much hoping to get some advice here related to a fascinating and
  rather difficult problem. I'm a relatively green programmer (been
  taking loads of online classes) and am designing my first website
  with the goal of helping teachers sort their students. Here's the
  idea:
- Given a grade size of 50-75 elementary school students, teachers need
  to sort their grade into 2-4 new classes (for the upcoming school
  year) based on certain criteria. Each student has a set of data
  related to their identity, as well as their academic strengths and
  weaknesses:
- Race, Gender, Math Proficiency(1-4), Reading Proficiency(1-4),
  Behavior(1-4)
- This group of students essentially needs to be sorted into these new
  classes so that each class has a relatively even distribution of
  students with diverse identities and academic needs.
- As in, each class needs a relatively even amount of boys and girls,
  white students and students of color, but *also* students with math
  related weaknesses, reading related weaknesses, and behavior issues.
  All of these variables would ideally be considered *together* while
  sorting a given grade.
- So there are a ton of variables involved and I'm having problems
  wrapping my mind around how to best program this. I initially had the
  idea of combining a student's academic skills together (so math,
  reading, & behavior when added together equal anywhere from 3-12) and
  rotating through each class, distributing students one at a time in a
  loop.
- This doesn't work because there's no guarantee that, while students
  with generally better or worse academic skills will be evenly sorted,
  a large amount of students with math deficiencies won't be placed in
  one class while reading or behavior problems won't be placed in
  another. We're trying to avoid that, having as diverse of a group of
  classes as possible (so that each teacher doesn't have an incredibly
  easy math or difficult reading/behavior class next year).
- I hope this makes sense. I'd love to show y'all the code but at this
  point I've mostly just got SQL databases and lots of questions (lol).
  If anyone has any ideas (or could potentially point me in the
  direction of algorithms that help solve these types of problems)
  please let me know!

***Thank you so so much!***

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: My apologies! Thanks for your response

Comment: That said: my naive assessment would be - you have to find a way to define *even distribution* and how to optimize it; the three proficiencies already look *weighted* so a simple average may suffice - optimizing for the smallest variation in averages; gender and race could probably be similarly weighted and optimized for low variance of the means.

Comment: Related: [Algorithm to create fair / evenly matched teams based on player rankings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363341/algorithm-to-create-fair-evenly-matched-teams-based-on-player-rankings), Found that searching with `algorithm to optimize gender distribution` - but those search terms may not be quite right. Maybe something like `algorithm to optimize diversity of traits`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much for your help!